# how to extract alpaha numeric string

Tags: regex

how i extract sub string like **370-N7109-Z 152** from

**MFJ
370-N7109-Z 152
Matte finish
Choker/ vamki**

or **AK038121918 10821** from

**ak
AK038121918
10821
Matte Necklace Set**

I am trying regex but unable to create any regex.only able to get numbers but i am trying to get regex which works on both condition in above example

There is no constant size after prefix which AK or MFJ but it will contains sequence of number with mix of Alpha and special char sometimes. substring always starts with prefix that i am saved in db like AK, MFJ, PC's, NEW etc

Comment: First, you might want to have some predetermined and repetitive pattern; in first example you substring with different pattern and in another - different.. it's impossible to guess when you want to do what.. you need some basis.

Comment: @GIorgi Tsiklauri MFJ or AK is known prefix in string

Comment: How long is prefix? is it constant size?

Comment: Voting to close as being too broad, because you have not provided logic by which we know where the target string begins and ends.

Comment: No constant size

Comment: @Kandy then by what rule we're expected to substring? do you have anything we could grisp our hand on?

Comment: Do you have maybe space after a prefix, and is it constant factor?

Comment: I have to obtain sequence on the basis of Prefix then after only alpha numeric string starts it may contains space or starts with numbers and lastly ends with number its self

Comment: Your edit is again unclear. In one case your substring starts with numeric character and in another - with alphabet character.

Comment: @Giorgi Tsiklauri one thing i noticed that after prefix its always starts with space or number and end with number

Comment: Very vague... and even this is your `notice`.. you're not sure here as well.

Comment: @Giorgi tsiklauri I only sure about prefix which comes surely in start of sub string and I am maintaining the prefix code in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution, but might need clarification in case of more general pattern needed:

```
import re

m = """
MFJ 370-N7109-Z 152 Matte finish Choker/ vamki
ak AK038121918 10821 Matte Necklace Set
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"(MFJ|ak|PC's|NEW)\s(.*)(?=Matte)", re.I)

res = re.findall(pattern, m)
for r in res:
    print(r[1])
```

Returns:

```
370-N7109-Z 152 
AK038121918 10821
```

Comment: thanks for help its helps me to come upto my result with some modification. Thanks :)

Comment: I am very happy to hear it :)

Comment: is it possible to replace (?=Matte) with any number but number should be include in substring like (\d) but this remove last number i dont want to remove last number but end with number

Comment: Yes, you could for example look into the re.replace() method